# Improving an OpenCL kernel for a Perceptron neural network

Tags: performance, opencl

I've been doing a lot of OpenGL and shaders before, and now, I decided to give a try to OpenCL. I watched some online tutorials, and started reading books on the subject. In order to better understand, and because I believe that the best way to learn is by intelligently trying and learning from the issues that arose while doing so, I decided to start implementing a kernel for a fully-connected perceptron.

For those who don't know what that is, I'll explain the basic idea. It is a neural network in which each neuron of a layer is connected to every neurons of the next layer. Each neuron has but one action to perform: performing the sum of all the neurons from the previous layer, weighted by a different value for each neuron.

This seemed simple enough to implement, and after reading the paper "Parallel Neural Network Training with OpenCL" I implemented it in the following way

- Each layer being dependent on the previous one, they're being run sequentially by the host
- For computing a layer, I run my kernel with a global work size of the number of neurons within the layer (which can be quite huge, tens of thousand for instance). That makes it so that all the neurons are performing its sum independently to one another.
- Each neuron (identified by its global_work_id) performs the weighted sum with all the neurons from the previous layer.

Here is my fully functional opencl kernel:

```
/**
* @brief Computes one layer of the perceptron given the previous one and the
* weights
* The kernel is run once for each layer.
* The work items are each tasked with computing the output of a single neuron
* of the out layer.
*
* @param out_layer_size
*   Size of the output layer (number of elements in the output array that will
*   contain the result for each neuron).
* @param in_layer_size
*   Number of elements of the input layer
* @param in_value
*   Values of the neuron in the previous layer
* @param in_weights
*   Array containing the weights for each input neuron. It is organised as a
*   two dimensional matrix, written by concatenating each line in the array
*   [ w11, w12, w13, ...
*     w21, w22, w23, ...
*     ..., ..., ..., ...
*   ]
*   Where wij is the weight linking the neuron i of the input layer to the
*   neuron j of the output layer
* @param out_values
*   Computed values for the current layer
*/
void kernel perceptron(global const int* in_layer_size, global const int* out_layer_size, global const float *in_value, global const float* in_weights, global float* out_values)
{
    private const int global_id = get_global_id(0);
    private const int out_layer_s = *out_layer_size;
    private const int in_layer_s = *in_layer_size;
    private const int offset = out_layer_s * global_id;

    private float sum = 0.;
    for(int i=0; i < in_layer_s; i++) {
        sum += in_weights[i*out_layer_s+global_id] * in_value[i];
    }
    //out_values[global_id] = sigma(sum);
    out_values[global_id] = sum;
}
```

And here is how I invoke it:

```
queue.enqueueNDRangeKernel(kernel, cl::NullRange,cl::NDRange(number of neurons within layer),cl::NullRange);
```

I realize that the bottleneck of this kernel is the implementation of the weighted sum. It would be really helpful if someone could explain how I could improve upon this to make it faster.

I probably don't make proper use of the different memory regions, I'm thinking essentially of the local memory that I don't even use.

Just to give you an idea of performance (that is on an Nvidia GTX 660M), I'll show you some of the times I achieved. Each value is the number of neurons per layer:

- 2500, 10 000, 2500 : 0.018s  ~ 60FPS. It's about 4 to 5 times faster than on my processor (Intel Core i7 running at 2.40GHz)
- 100 000, 100 000, 500: 140s  -> which I guess isn't surpsising since each neuron in the second layer has to perform the weighted sum of 100 000 elements. Running this on my processor yields about the same results.

Comment: Are you looking for optimizations for the 100k,100k,500 case, or a general performance boost? Which is more common, the 1st case (2500,10k,1500), the 2nd case, or some other range of input sizes?

Comment: The question was more general. I guess the first case is much much more common. It's pretty rare to need more neurons than that. The idea is more to get a sense of how I could improve the kernel itself, maybe making better use of memories, optimizing the loop...

Answer (score 1):

As you told, bottleneck is the weighted summ. That's not hard to be, as at each layer every WI (Work Item) is doing a lot of IO operations in comparison to number of arithmetic operations. I have no experience in neural networks, but for me problem looks like poor memory access pattern on GPU.

Potentially, that can be solved by organizing your WI into local WGs (Work Groups). As every WI needs to process all data from prev. layer, I guess that all WI in WG can load some amount of data into local memory, process them and than to next bunch of data. This will make your algorithm much more cache friendly. Pseudo-code of kernel looks like:

```
void kernel Kernel(
__global const int  in_layer_size, 
__global const int  out_layer_size, 
__global const float    *in_value, 
__global const float    *in_weights, 
__global float      *out_values){

__local float buffer[SOME_SIZE];
__global const float* p_in  = in_value;
__global float* p_out = out_values;

const int 
    global_id   = get_global_id(0),
    local_id    = get_local_id(0),
    num_buffers = in_layer_size / SOME_SIZE,
    offset      = out_layer_size * global_id;

float sum = 0.0f;
for(int i=0; i < num_buffers; i++){
    buffer[local_id] = p_in[local_id];
    barrier(CLK_LOCAL_MEM_FENCE);

    //Process all data inside buffer by every WI in WG
    //...

    p_in += SOME_SIZE;
    out_values += SOME_SIZE;
    }

//...
return;
```

}

So, you're sliding with the window of fixed size & calculating data within & then going to next window. Al data operations are done independently, Work Items are only using same data at same time. Optimal size of local group is Device- and Kernel- dependent.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in many ways. 
But the most generic way, without changing how your kernel behaves is to do it is reusing your workgroup size (whatever you selected, or default) and reuse the memory accesses from the group.

I would suggest something like this:

**NOTE:** I removed thouse ugly pointers for single values. OpenCL supports this, and it is much easier. There is no need to create a memory zone, just do `clSetKernelArg(kernel, arg_index, sizeof(cl_float), &size);` Where `cl_float size = the_size;`.

```
#define IN_LOCAL_SIZE 4096 //Because 16KB/4B (for each float)

void kernel perceptron(global const int in_layer_size, global const int out_layer_size, global const float *in_value, global const float* in_weights, global float* out_values)
{
    const int global_id = get_global_id(0);
    __local float in_buffer[IN_LOCAL_SIZE];

    float sum = 0.0f;
    event_t ev;
    int j;
    //For each full buffer
    for(j=0; j < (in_layer_size/IN_LOCAL_SIZE)-1; i++) {
        ev = async_work_group_copy(in_buffer, in_value+j*IN_LOCAL_SIZE, IN_LOCAL_SIZE, ev);
        wait_group_events(1,&ev);
        barrier(CLK_LOCAL_MEM_FENCE);
        for(int i=0; i < IN_LOCAL_SIZE; i++) {
            sum += in_weights[(i+j*IN_LOCAL_SIZE)*out_layer_size+global_id] * in_buffer[i];
        }
    }
    //Last one
    ev = async_work_group_copy(in_buffer, in_value+j*IN_LOCAL_SIZE, in_layer_size%IN_LOCAL_SIZE, ev);
    wait_group_events(1,&ev);
    barrier(CLK_LOCAL_MEM_FENCE);
    for(int i=0; i < in_layer_size%IN_LOCAL_SIZE; i++) {
        sum += in_weights[(i+j*IN_LOCAL_SIZE)*out_layer_size+global_id] * in_buffer[i];
    }
    out_values[global_id] = sum;
}
```

However, if the output size is small (100k, 250k, 500), then you will have just 500 work items, which is not optimal. In that case you should reshape the algorithm.

One possible way to do it is that each workitem works in the inner layer, performing sums, and the whole work group creates one output out of all the work items. That would be easy, since you can control the sums inside the workgroup easily.

But maybe other approaches fit better your problem.

Comment: In general case you can't be sure, that your Device can execute particular kernel with fixed local group size. So, hardcoding local WG size in code is IMO, not best practice except for small local groups

Comment: I am not fixing the local group size. I am fixing the local memory used by the kernel. Which is at least 16KB. I am answering properly to the OP question, since he is using the default work size.

Answer (score 1):

You can make large improvements by caching in_values in local memory. The fewer times you have to read each element of in_values from global memory, the better.

I have come up with a solution that caches the maximum number of input values, and reads each element from global memory only once per work group. This is done by copying a block of in_values at a time, processing it against all out_values, and moving on to the next block. There is also a local array of floats used to reduce the work items' sums of each block.

pseudocode:

```
  output elements assumed to be set to 0 already
  for each block of input values:
    cache the input block
    for each target output value:
      reset local sum to 0
      for each element this work item is responsible for:
        read the weight, multiply, and add to sum
      reduce sums to a single value, ADD value to output element
```

I haven't had a chance to run this through a profiler or debugger yet, but I will give it a try when I am back at my home PC. (no opencl tools at my office workstation). Make sure to queue kernel with group size equal to the GROUP_SIZE constant. Also, only create a single group per compute unit on your device.

real code:

```
//experiment with GROUP_SIZE to discover the optimal value for your device
//this needs to be equal to local_work_size passed into clEnqueueNDRangeKernel
//use a multiple of CL_KERNEL_PREFERRED_WORK_GROUP_SIZE_MULTIPLE
//max. for most devices is 256
#define GROUP_SIZE = 64;

// IN_VALUE_CACHE_SIZE is the number of floats from in_value to copy to local memory at a time
//assuming GROUP_SIZE can be up to 256, sizeof(float)=4,  and local memory size is 32kb, full saturation can be achieved with the following:
//(32768 - (256 * 4)) /4 = 7936
//try another multiple of 1024 (6144, 4096... )if there is trouble with this value
#define IN_VALUE_CACHE_SIZE = 7936;

void kernel perceptron(global const int* in_layer_size, global const int* out_layer_size, global const float *in_value, global const float* in_weights, global float* out_values)
{
    private const int global_id = get_global_id(0);
    private const int out_layer_s = *out_layer_size;
    private const int in_layer_s = *in_layer_size;
    private const int offset = out_layer_s * global_id;

    private const int item_id = get_local_id(0);    
    private const int group_id = get_group_id(0);   
    private const int group_count = get_num_groups(0);  


    local float result_buffer[GROUP_SIZE];

    local float in_value_cache[IN_VALUE_CACHE_SIZE];
    int i,j,k;

    //init the block to 0, in case there are fewer than IN_VALUE_CACHE_SIZE values in total
    for(i=item_id; i<IN_VALUE_CACHE_SIZE; i+= GROUP_SIZE){
        in_value_cache[i] = 0.0;
    }
    barrier(CL_LOCAL_MEM_FENCE);


    private float sum = 0.0;
    event_t e;
    int copy_total = 0;
    int copy_offset;

    for(i=0; i<in_layer_s; i+=IN_VALUE_CACHE_SIZE){
        //cap the number of values to copy to local memory if loop is near the end of the input data
        copy_total = IN_VALUE_CACHE_SIZE;
        if((copy_total + i*IN_VALUE_CACHE_SIZE) > in_layer_s){
            copy_total = in_layer_s - i*IN_VALUE_CACHE_SIZE;
        }           
        //copy the next block of values
        e = async_work_group_copy(in_value_cache, in_value + i * 4, copy_total, 0);
        wait_group_events(1, &e);

        for(j=group_id; j<out_layer_s; j+=group_count){
            sum = 0.0;

            //need to reset result_buffer[item_id] as well
            //this is in case there are fewer than GROUP_SIZE input values remaining  ie copy_total < GROUP_SIZE
            result_buffer[item_id] = 0.0;

            for(k=item_id; k<copy_total; k+=GROUP_SIZE){
                sum += in_value_cache[k] * in_weights[(k+i) + j * out_layer_s];
            }
            result_buffer[item_id] = sum;

            //simple O(n) reduction can be optimized further
            if(item_id == 0){
                for(k=1;k<GROUP_SIZE;k++){
                    sum += result_buffer[k];
                }
                out_values[j] += sum;
            }
            barrier(CL_LOCAL_MEM_FENCE);
        }

    }
}
```

This will handle input of any size, so you can try it with as many elements as you have global memory for.